# Best practices to develop a generic microservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

For a project, we will develop some micro services. They will have many common parts like configurations class, filters...
I search the best practice et method to develop it.

For the moment, i had create a generic micro service, forked by all to develop module above it. But is not convenient and some modification in one web service may be would cause some difficult for the next merge of the generic MS.

Do you have any idea to develop it or sources to inspire me?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one or more libraries containing Abstract classes that implement the shared functionality.

Import one or more of the libraries into each individual project.

Extend the Abstract classes in the individual projects.

Use Spring annotations (for instance @Component or
@RestController) in the individual projects,
not in the common libraries.

Use some Spring annotations (for instance @Scheduled) in the common libraries.
If you do this, allow the individual projects to override the values in these annotations.
For example,

```
@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${common.thing.initialDelayString:10_000}",
    fixedDelayString = "${common.thing.fixedDelayString:60_000}")
```

The example annotation includes default values and allow the individual projects to override the values as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your response DwB.
So, if i understand, i can create a SecurityConfigurationGeneric in this library, declare some security points (add stateless for the server, security filter...), and surchage it in my micro service app like SecurityConfiguration extends SecurityConfigurationGeneric and add more specific point like security endpoint and roles?

Comment: Yes and no.  The word "generic" already has a definition in Java; don't use it for anything that is not related to "generics".  Create an "AbstractSecurityConfiguration" class int he library.

Comment: Ok I understanding ^^ Thanks DwB.
I will test it and do feedback after.